# how to make a php function work on onother page

Tags: php, ajax

i have the index.php which  contains the news , i want wen click readmore button to redirect to readmore.php page and show the news_desc from the db for that news

index.php :

```
           <div class="content_container">  
      <h3> <?php echo $rowNews['newstitle'];?></h3> 
      <p><?php echo $rowNews['news_bio'];?></p>
              <img src="<?php echo $rowNews['news_image'];?>" alt="Smiley face" height="191" width="140">
       <div class="button_small">
                   <a href="readmore.php">Read more</a>
      </div><!--close button_small-->
    </div><!--close content_container-->

        <?php 
      }
      } 
        ?>
```

readmore.php :

```
    <p id = "fullNewsP"  style="font-size:25px">news_desc here</p>      

    </div><!--close content_container-->
```

Comment: pass querystring with the URL

Comment: Like this :- <a href="readmore.php?q=<?php echo $rowNews['newstitle'];?>">Read more</a>.

Comment: thank you  Yash Parekh
but  how to handle this in readmore.php

Comment: Use $_GET['q'] to fetch the data from the database using select query...

Comment: Like :- select * from news_desc where news_title=$_GET['q']

Comment: $selectNews = "SELECT * FROM `news` where newstitle = $_GET['q']"
this gave me a syntax error

Comment: $selectNews = "SELECT * FROM news where newstitle = ".$_GET['q'].  This is what you are looking for

Comment: Yash Parekh thank you vary much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.php**

```
<a href="readmore.php?q=<?php echo $rowNews['newstitle'];?>">Read more</a>
```

**readmore.php**

```
$selectNews = "SELECT * FROM news where newstitle = ".$_GET['q'];
```

Comment: Never use GET/POST data on your SQL query directly like this, its just inviting SQL Injection (a kind of db hacking). Rather parse the query string data and escape it properly, even better use PDO prepared statement.

Comment: @leninhasda I'm agree with you but that's not related with the question. Its a whole different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your more button should be sending the id of the news article.

```
<a href="readmore.php?=<?php echo $dbid; ?>">Read more</a>
```

Then on your readmore.php page:

```
$db_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

Then pull all the data from the DB and display it as required. This is it in it's simplest form. Check all your security settings and stuff before implementing this, but it'll give you a good idea.